# Find the Largest Area of Square Inside Two Rectangles(Intersection)

Tags: java, algorithm, intersection, rectangles

There exist n rectangles in a 2D plane. We have 2D integer arrays bottomLeft and topRight, both of size n x 2, representing the bottom-left and top-right coordinates of the ith rectangle respectively. We can select a region formed from the intersection of two of the given rectangles such that it is largest (0 if no intersection).
This is my solution to it, i am getting a few test cases passed but getting stuck in Others

```
class Solution {
    public long largestSquareArea(int[][] bottomLeft, int[][] topRight) {
        int n = bottomLeft.length;
        int maxArea = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                int[] intersection = intersect(
                        new int[]{bottomLeft[i][0], bottomLeft[i][1], topRight[i][0], topRight[i][1]},
                        new int[]{bottomLeft[j][0], bottomLeft[j][1], topRight[j][0], topRight[j][1]});
                if (intersection != null) {
                    int sideLength = Math.min(intersection[2] - intersection[0], intersection[3] - intersection[1]);
                    maxArea = Math.max(maxArea, sideLength * sideLength);
                }
            }
        }

        return maxArea;
    }

    private int[] intersect(int[] rect1, int[] rect2) {
        int x1 = Math.max(rect1[0], rect2[0]);
        int y1 = Math.max(rect1[1], rect2[1]);
        int x2 = Math.min(rect1[2], rect2[2]);
        int y2 = Math.min(rect1[3], rect2[3]);
        if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2) {
            return new int[]{x1, y1, x2, y2};
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. That there are no answers or even comments 2 hours after you posted the question probably means I am not alone. Why, for example, is the number of rectangles, `n`, the same as the `n` in the `n x 2` arrays? Are there two of those `n x 2` arrays for each rectangle? If the pairs are meant to identify the locations of the rectangles why aren't they instead coordinates? You vaguely suggest the objective in the title but do not state it precisely in the body of the question.

Comment: *"getting stuck"*: what exactly does that mean? You got an error? A wrong return value? Too long execution time? For which input?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE] on an online playground and edit its link into the question. Make it clear which test cases are failing.

Comment: This is a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-largest-area-of-square-inside-two-rectangles/). Are you getting time exceeded errors?

Comment: Found an issue; you should declare `maxArea` and `sideLength` as `long`, otherwise you will get an overflow with some test cases.